# Pycharm - storing code in memory/avoid re-running entire code

Tags: python, pycharm

I am running models from Tensorflow/Keras libraries in Pycharm (2019 edition) and would like to know if there is a way to store the results of the previously run code into memory and then only run the code beneath those results as opposed to having to run the entire code again and wait for the train/test split, fitting of the model, etc. to be carried out every time?

I referred to the question below asked a few years ago and it looks like Pycharm did not have this option at the time - I am hoping it has been made possible since then?

[PyCharm: Storing variables in memory to be able to run code from a "checkpoint"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064556/pycharm-storing-variables-in-memory-to-be-able-to-run-code-from-a-checkpoint)

I know Jupyter Notebook can do this since you can run every line of code cell by cell and only run what you want to instead of the entire code all over and waste time. I am hoping this is possible otherwise will consider using a different IDE.

Comment: I think you are looking for [code cells in scientific mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html), which seem to be limited to PyCharm Professional. Visual Studio has "Jupyter code cells": [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py)

Comment: You have a lot of possibilities: you explicit save state at specific point, and you import libraries and read state (you can run also just few lines, directly in console). If you choose for a different IDE: please answer this question, so we know how to do (but I think it is not much a question of IDE, but of python/programming style)

Comment: I already attempted running only the 'bottom' portion of the code (i.e. the one excluding all the calculations) within the console but it still re-runs the entire script again. It is a bit disappointing that it is only available on the Professional version of Pycharm.

Comment: For anyone referring to this in the future - a possible solution to this issue can be to save the results of the model and thereafter load it back as a variable and use that variable for anything else. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#how_to_save_and_load_a_model